Why doesn't Spring Batch include script engine dependencies in tests for ScriptItemProcessor?
I’m working with Spring Batch's ScriptItemProcessor and noticed that when testing various scripting languages (e.g., JavaScript, Groovy, JRuby), the engine dependencies (like groovy-jsr223 for Groovy) are not included by default, not even in the test scope. As a result, some tests are skipped depending on the availability of these engines in the environment.
For example, in the ScriptItemProcessorTests class, the test for Groovy looks like this:
@Test
void testGroovyScriptSourceSimple() throws Exception {
    assumeTrue(languageExists("groovy"));
    ScriptItemProcessor<String, Object> scriptItemProcessor = new ScriptItemProcessor<>();
    scriptItemProcessor.setScriptSource("item.toUpperCase();", "groovy");
    scriptItemProcessor.afterPropertiesSet();

    assertEquals("SS", scriptItemProcessor.process("ss"), "Incorrect transformed value");
}

The test uses assumeTrue(languageExists("groovy"));, meaning it will only run if the Groovy engine is available. However, the Groovy dependency is not included in the Spring Batch project, which means the test is skipped unless I manually add it.
My questions are:

Why are these script engine dependencies (like groovy-jsr223) not included by default in the Spring Batch project, even for testing purposes?

Is there a specific reason why the framework avoids adding these dependencies, given that these scripts are part of the tests?

Shouldn’t we ensure that these tests are run as part of the testing process, even if it means adding the required script engine dependencies?


I understand that different environments may not have all scripting engines installed, but I think it would be beneficial to run these tests automatically if the dependencies were added to the test scope.
ScriptItemProcessorTests skipped due to missing script engine dependencies.

Those dependencies are optional. Not everyone is using the script item processor, therefore it does not make sense for these dependencies to be required at compile time. Jackson is a good example as well, not everyone wants to serialize the batch meta-data to json (that's why the dependency is optional and should be added if needed).
Regarding test dependencies, there is no reason those dependencies are not included. This is probably an oversight and should be fixed.

Thank you so much for your answer! If it's okay with you, I'd love to share the relevant PR updates with you.

Sure! you are welcome.
